# Find out if a server can handle 100 users in one minute using JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am testing an API endpoint. I would like to know if the server can handle 100 users in one minute.

This is the thread configuration that I am currently using.

My question is:

- did I configure the threads, ramp-up period, and duration parameter correctly?
- How much ramp up period is ideal, against the number of threads?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend either decreasing the ramp-up or increasing the test duration because with your current settings you will have 100 users online only **during the last second of the test**

So set "Duration" to 120 seconds so during first minute your threads would be ramping up followed by another minute of 100 online users or go for something like:

- 30 seconds of ramp-up
- 180 seconds of duration

You may find i.e. [Ultimate Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/) easier to use, it's default workload pattern seems to match your scenario:

[image]

and you will be able to play with ramp-up, ramp-down and time to hold the load and see the anticipated threads count in the chart.

You can install Ultimate Thread Group as a part of "Custom Thread Groups" bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager/)

The whole point of ramp-up is that your should be increasing the load **gradually** so you could correlate the increasing load with other metrics (throughout, response times, errors, etc.)

As per [JMeter Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group):

> The ramp-up period tells JMeter how long to take to "ramp-up" to the full number of threads chosen. If 10 threads are used, and the ramp-up period is 100 seconds, then JMeter will take 100 seconds to get all 10 threads up and running. Each thread will start 10 (100/10) seconds after the previous thread was begun. If there are 30 threads and a ramp-up period of 120 seconds, then each successive thread will be delayed by 4 seconds.

> **Ramp-up needs to be long enough to avoid too large a work-load at the start of a test, and short enough that the last threads start running before the first ones finish (unless one wants that to happen).**

> **Start with Ramp-up = number of threads and adjust up or down as needed.**